# No audio in fresh installed Lubuntu 15.10

Tags: sound, lubuntu, 15.10, dell

I am a new user of Lubuntu OS. I installed fresh download from Ubuntu website.

Lubuntu 15.10; kernel 4.2.0.34; version 5.2.1.22

I cannot get any audio out through the speaker out and faintly on the headphone jack on a Dell latitude D 600.

Answer (score 0):

On my netbook I had similar issues.  If fixed them by installing Pulse Audio Volume Control, `pavucontrol`, from the Lubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

I only do ubuntu 14.04. But I have found no audio out problems are about the permissions given to /dev/snd and the files there. On my systems the files have permissions for user root and group audio.

Note no world permissions so a user must belong to group audio to have permission.

```
ls -l /dev/snd to see permissions.

.....@xen2[2145]ls -l /dev/snd
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       80 Mar 22 17:42 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Mar 22 17:42 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Mar 22 17:42 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Mar 22 17:42 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Mar 22 17:42 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Mar 22 18:56 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Mar 22 17:42 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Mar 22 17:44 pcmC1D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Mar 22 17:42 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Mar 22 17:42 timer

If your /dev/snd files have the same permissions 
grep audio /etc/group and see if you are in that group.  

I added my username to group audio with 
sudo usermod -a -G audio "myusername"
do not quote " your user name.

I use fvwm as a window manager and start gnome stuff in an xterm. Or Gnome-Terminial.

my quick test of sound
gnome-control-center sound see if the sound effect output. 
No then do it with sudo gnome-control-center sound and see if sound effects work. 
if it works for sudo or root and not for you then it is permissions.
```

Comment: Ubuntu and Lubuntu are quite different in their default audio setups.  Ubuntu always worked out of the box for me, Lubuntu never has.

Comment: I've done, redhat free starting with 0.9... thru till  fedora 3 thru 15 and then went to ubuntu 10 and fedora and this year finally ubuntu 14.04.   I use fvwm not gnome or unity.   sound was always an issue in ubuntu for me.   Using fvwm as a window manage meant I never had an out of the box from about redhat 4  I think.